# Javascript print node.js version and modules versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

running a node.js server and I want to display in my javascript code the nodejs version and all it's module and versions. something like
console.log(MODULENAME.version), .. 
don't know how to do that and its syntaxe .
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 12):

You can get this from your package.json:

```
const packageDetails = require('./package.json');

console.log('Platform: ', process.platform);
console.log('Node version: ', process.version);
console.log('Node dependencies: ', process.versions);
console.log('Server version: ', packageDetails.version);
let keys = Object.keys(packageDetails.dependencies);
console.log('Modules: ');
keys.forEach((k) => {
    console.log(`${k}: ${packageDetails.dependencies[k]}`);
})
```

Comment: thanks, work like a charm  ! reason why process.platform and process.x do return empty string ?

Comment: Oh, interesting, they don't for me, on Win32. Probably a platform thing! I'm using Node 8.4, this may also be the reason!

Comment: Who I migrate this to typescript?

Comment: You can create an app.ts file, with the same code, you'll need to install the Node.js types:  npm i @types/node. Then compile: tsc app.ts and to run: node app.js.